# Contenteditable Inline Style in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, inline, contenteditable

I'm able to force browsers to use inline css ex:style="...." by using styleWithCSS execcommand. That however doesn't work for IE. IE still uses HTML tags rather then inline css. Is there a way to force IE to use inline styling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [styleWithCSS for IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646420/stylewithcss-for-ie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not by using `execCommand()`, no. You'll need to style the selection contents manually to have that kind of control. My [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library's [CSS class applier module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) may be able to help point you in the right direction.